# Grunt/Bower/Component: Handling dependencies?

Tags: dependencies, gruntjs, components, bower, package-managers

I have build something like a base template/workflow for creating websites, mostly using Grunt.

Part of that template is the Modernizr feature detection library, one of my Grunt tasks depends on.

At the moment I just have stored that dependency in my `bower.json` manifest. That brings two problems to the table:

1. I need to update the project's name, version, author etc. in both my `bower.json` and `package.json` (for Grunt).
2. I don't like the fact that my dependencies are spreaded out like this – I would need to run `npm install` and `bower install ...` before I can start to work. (Not that its a great effort, but to me thats really counter intuitive.)

**Is there a smarter, more general way to handle such dependencies?**

I already took a look into using `component.json` files which can be read by various package managers (I looked a DUO in particular), but I am not sure if thats what I actually need. There seems to be a build process included, but I already build through Grunt.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Yeoman generator.

If you want to implement Yeoman generator for your own project, I will leave an useful tutorial link here:

[1] [http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-your-own-yeoman-generator--cms-20040?post_id=1026796690681657_1026796687348324#*=*](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-your-own-yeoman-generator--cms-20040?post_id=1026796690681657_1026796687348324#_=_)

[2] http://yeoman.io/authoring/

**1**. basically, `index.js` of Yeoman generator can prompt an user for his input, store it, and write it on any file. Because of the same demand like you, I am currently creating my own generator to put  my favorite pieces into bower.json and package.json all together, and I used those articles usefully.

I also highly recommend you to take a close look at other generators on their git repos. The generator is written in Javascript with both Node.js and Yeoman's API.

**2**. It's easy. you can create your own alias on `.bash_profile`.

- open up your terminal (I am on OSX)
- past `echo 'alias coinstall=npm install && bower install --save-dev' | tee ~/.bash_profile && source ~/.bash_profile`  and enter
- you will have the hidden `.bash_profile` file
- now you can install npm and bower by typing `coinstall`!